# Storing the value of CheckBox in WiX

Tags: checkbox, wix, registry, wix3.6

I have authored an installer using Wix 3.6 RC. I have a checkbox in the dialog UI which is disabled and unchecked initially. There is a "Verify" button next to it. When I press this button a custom action gets executed (immediate) and sets a value of parameter which decides whether check box gets enabled or not. Here is the code:

```
<Control Id="VirtualCheckBox"
                 Type="CheckBox"
                 CheckBoxValue="1"
                 X="35" Y="100"
                 Width="160" Height="20"
                 Disabled="yes"
                 Text="!(loc.VirtualizationDlg_ChkBox)" Property="ENABLEVIRTUALIZATION">
  <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[INTEGRATED = "1"]]></Condition>
  <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[INTEGRATED = "0"]]></Condition>
</Control>
```

I am storing this value of checkbox in registry:

```
<Component Id="Virtualization_RegistryEntries" Guid="GUID-IS-HERE">
    <Condition>Not Installed</Condition>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU"
                 Key="Software\!(loc.CompanyName)\!(loc.ProductName)">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Virtualization" Value="[ENABLEVIRTUALIZATION]" KeyPath="yes"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
```

Now I have to do this:
1) If user does not click the Verify button : Registry gets value 0
2) If he clicks button (CA gets false and checkbox remains disabled) : Registry gets value 0
3) If he clicks button and checkbox enables but he does not check the checkbox : Registry gets value 0
4) If he clicks button and checkbox enables and he does check the check box : Registry gets value 1

Mine is not working at only one condition, when he checks this, registry does get 1 but either it is disabled or remains unchecked the registry gets nothing.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried giving your variables a default value?

```
<Property Id="ENABLEVIRTUALIZATION" Value="0" />
```

Something as simple as that should do the trick!

Comment: Ok I try this, the check box is checked but remain disabled in UI and registry entry shows as 0 (great). But now I have a valid Verify button action and checkbox enables (but still checked). and I go ahead with installation, I saw registry value still be 0 (oh man!!!) rather it should be 1. This is where problem lies.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because the checkbox is only unchecked when the property it is using has no value.  By assigning a default value to the property it uses, regardless of what it is the control will be checked. I am still looking to a solution to this problem.